# Как создавать временные переменные в Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Подскажите, как быть в такой ситуации:

1. Отправляется action — REQUEST_LOGIN, идёт запрос авторизации на сервер.
2. Приходит ответ с ошибкой, текст ошибки записывается в store с помощью редьюсера.
3. При обновлении страницы текст ошибки остаётся, так как был сохранён в store

Как можно переделать 1 и 2 шаги, чтобы избежать третьего?

Comment: По-моему (3) -- фича; сделать крестик закрытия на ошибке

Answer (score 2):

При обновлении страницы данные в store **всегда** очищаются.Ты, либо используешь local storage, либо что-то не то подразумеваешь под обновлением стрраницы.

Как избежать: при размонтировании компонента отправлять еще один action (RESET_STATE), который будет обнулять состояние store

Comment: Да, я записываю их в localStorage. Тоже думал при размонтировании обнулять, но если обновить страницу или закрыть браузер к примеру, то размонтировка не помогает :(

Comment: @ikerya Нужный вам lifecycle hook (unmount), срабатывает и при закрытии страницы браузера, и при ее обновлении. Видимо, что-то делаете не так. Попробуйте накидать пример в песочнице.

Comment: Обычный useEffect(() => { return () => alert('unmount') }) у меня при обновлении и закрытии страницы не сработал